# Enable remote connections option not available on chrome Remote desktop app on Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to setup remote desktop access to a chrome box. Plan is to be able to access the chrome box from any where by just entering a pin and I don't want user using the chrome box to generate a key for me and send it over to me.

I thought chrome remote desktop app would help me achieve this, but Enable remote connections option is not available on chrome Remote desktop app on Chrome OS. This option is available if the app is installed on windows and I was able to remote in. Is there any option to achieve the same in Chrome OS?

Answer (score 0):

Star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471639 to show your support for adding this feature.